# Coercion related issue

Tags: javascript

```
 0==0 // true
0==null // false
```

Why 0==0 true but 0==null false can anyone explain how this coercion works. Which is better to use implicit or explicit and how can I know more about this and as per industry based practices which I should use to make it a habit.

Comment: Why do you expect `0==null` to be true?

Comment: See [the specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islooselyequal).